# remove duplicate objects from list

Tags: python

It's easy to remove duplicates from a list of simple objects by transforming the list into a set:

```
l = ['Joe','Peter','Paul','Joe','Peter','Paul']
s = set(l)
```

I tried the same with somewhat more complex objects and did not succeed:

```
class fullname:

    def __init__(self, firstname, surname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.surname = surname

firstnames=['Joe','Peter','Paul','Joe','Peter','Paul']
surnames = ['Miller','Smith','McCartney','Miller','Smith','McCartney']


fullnames = []
for i in range(len(firstnames)):
    fullnames.append(fullname(firstnames[i],surnames[i]))
```

The list fullnames holds 3 pairs with equal attribute values but python does not interpret the objects as equal.
Is there an elegant way to remove duplicates (e.g. objects with identical attribute values) of complex objects from a list?

Thanks to the hint from jonrsharpe, I found this solution:

```
class fullname:

    def __init__(self, firstname, surname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.surname = surname

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.surname == other.surname and self.firstname == other.firstname:
            return True
        else:
            return False

firstnames =['Joe','Peter','Paul','Joe','Peter','Paul']
surnames = ['Miller','Smith','McCartney','Miller','Smith','McCartney']

# create list of objects
fullnames = []
for i in range(len(firstnames)):
    fullnames.append(fullname(firstnames[i],surnames[i]))

# copy singular objects to list nodup
nodup = []
for element in fullnames:
    if element not in nodup:
        nodup.append(element)

for each in nodup:
    print(each.firstname,each.surname)
```

Comment: implement the magic methods is stronger, but you can also use a comprehension: `print(set(f'{x.firstname} {x.surname}' for x in fullnames))`

Comment: @PRMoreau this comprehension is ok if you need the strings only. In my real word problem, I have to preserve the objects.

Comment: of course that was a dumb move... it was the first step : `set_attr = set((n.firstname, n.surname) for n in fullnames)` then the second step could be `set_inst = [next((p for p in fullnames if (p.firstname, p.surname) == attrs)) for attrs in set_attr ]`  i admit it is less elegant :)